# using haproxy acl for website matching

Tags: haproxy

I am working with acl statment in haproxy 1.5 as shown below.

The idea is that for this specific site cop backend should be used but its not working. 
I tried with hdr(dom) and few other options but it didnt help.

Here is the code

```
frontend proxylb  
     bind *:80  
     maxconn 20000  
     acl is_cnn hdr_beg(host)  -i cnn.com  
     use_backend cop if is_cnn  
     default_backend  sf    
backend sf  
    balance     roundrobin  
    option httpclose  
    option forwardfor  
    cookie JSESSIONID prefix  
    server  proxy01  10.1.1.10:80 cookie A  check  
    server  proxy02  10.1.1.11:80 cookie A  check  

backend cop  
   balance roundrobin  
   option httpclose    
   option forwardfor  
   log global  
   cookie JSESSIONID prefix  
   server proxy03  10.1.1.12:80 cookie A  check
```

Comment: Can you post the full config?

Comment: sorry i am not able to format it in right way :(.

Comment: Your configuration seems ok in terms of the domain matching. I use the exact same configuration and it works fine.

Comment: Ok Thanks for checking. I will try to test it by some way to make sure it works.